# Airflow - create dynamic tasks based on config

Tags: airflow

I would like to manually trigger Airflow dag and pass parameters in this call. How to create DAG tasks based on the passed parameters?

Comment: might be a good hint https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67746038/how-to-dynamically-generate-airflow-tasks-in-a-loop-and-run-them-parallelly/67748904#67748904

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you can't dynamically create tasks in the sense you are asking now. Meaning, you can not add or delete tasks for a single run based on parameters that you give it. You always add the entire DAG, meaning also any consecutive DagRuns.

You have two options that might still get you to a satisfactory solution though.

1. Mapped tasks as explained here; https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.3.0/concepts/dynamic-task-mapping.html#simple-mapping
2. Generate a DAG based on some external resource. Example; we have a library on which we call `my_config.get_dag()` which will then create the DAG based on a json file.

Comment: Thank you. 1 means that I have to put the "parameters" statically into the code (DAG definition), right? And 2 means it e.g. reads some json and based on that json it creates the dag?

Comment: Is you take a look at the entire documentation page of the first option, I believe it shows you how a sql query could influence how many mapped tasks you get. Example, if my query returns 10 rows in a Pythonoperator, you can make it return a list with those 10 items. Then you can make the mapped operator execute once for each item in that list, creating 10 separate runs.

Answer (score 0):

I have a trick: pure-python task that pulls in the information about which dynamic tasks needs to be created from some external source (s3hook, `context["params"]`) and then it saves it into a variable:

```py
def read_dates_to_process() -> None:
    # get dates from some source
    Variable.set(key=DATES_TO_PROCESS_VAR, value=context["params"]["dates"], serialize_json=True)
```

Then you can use this variable to populate the tasks:

```py
with DAG():
    get_dates_to_process = PythonOperator(
        task_id="get_dates_to_process",
        python_callable=read_dates_to_process,
    )

    dates_to_process = Variable.get(DATES_TO_PROCESS_VAR, default_var=[], deserialize_json=True)

    prev = get_dates_to_process 
    
    for date in dates_to_process:
        task = python_task_operator(...)

        prev >> task # if you want it to be sequential
        prev = task
```

You need to run it once to populate variable, wait a bit for Airflow to refresh and then you can clear the `get_dates_to_process` task so that it and generated ones would get scheduled. Works like charm!